# PHP - checking if one value is larger then other, storing dynamically (restaurant menu)

Tags: php

I have a menu with a specific circumstance. There are 4-5 options, that a guest can choose to create their meal. However, with that one section, only the highest priced item should be counted towards the total, not the others.

The Price is updated via AJAX, so if one of the items is selected (via checkbox), the chose is automatically parsed.

Here is my issue :

```
$max = 0;

foreach ($prices as $k => $v) {
  if ($v['ingredienttype_id'] == '1' && $v['price'] > $max) { $max = $v['price']; }
}

foreach ($prices as $k => $v){
  if ($v['ingredienttype_id'] == '1' && $v['price'] < $max){ $prices[$k]['price'] = '0'; }
}
```

So in the first `foreach` loop i'm checking to see which one of the items submitted has the largest price, in the second, I set all the *other* items to $0. However, this seems "clunky" and has issues.

First, the initial item is never registered and doesn't update the price.

Second, when an item is added (i.e. $9), then removed and another item is added (i.e. $7), the second item is not counted towards the total because $max is set at $9. Is there a better way to handle this then my double `foreach` loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just refactor the code to generate the total automatically using [`max()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php)? That way, you don't need to reset the other prices to 0. For example, something like this would be far more readable:

```
$total = 0;
$prices = array();

foreach( $prices as $k => $v )
{
    $prices[] =  $v['price'];
}

$total+= max($prices);
```

Notice that we can pass an array to `max()` and have it return the maximum value inside the array:

> If the first and only parameter is an array, `max()` returns the highest
>   value in that array. If at least two parameters are provided, `max()`
>   returns the biggest of these values.

Comment: Because the items are checkboxes, the initial AJAX call will only have one item in the array, so it becomes the max. Now if the customer selects another item, we have two items in the array but the total already has the initial value. So this would just add the second value to the initial value. Also, there could be multiple items in the array from other menu sections. Perhaps if I keep a running total of "Section 1" and "Section 2", perform `max()` on "Section `" to weed out only the mad value, then add to "Section 2"? Cumbersome but it might work.